# Emoji in android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have developed android keyboard and I want to add emoji to it for example the code to view 'k' is

```
<Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
```

107 is the ascii code for 'k' letter you can find all ascii from this website
http://www.addressmunger.com/special_ascii_characters/

if you searched for 'k' you will get &#107; and my problem is if I want to put this emoji for example  the ascii I got is &#55357;&#56850; 
I don't know how to put this ascii in the xml .. any help?

Comment: This might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417028/how-to-map-accented-characters-in-keyboard-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find this **WILL NOT** work:

```
<Key android:codes="0x1F602" android:keyLabel="0x1F602"/>
```

Instead in the .xml layout file, for each emoji you want to add, create a line like this:

```
    <!--'Face with tears of joy' -->
<Key android:codes="0x1F602" android:keyLabel="\ud83d\ude02"/>
```

The "\ud83d\ude02" is called a Java Escape sequence (16 bit).

If your using [the standard SoftKeyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/95cf464c5a9f2bb7d6bf3a231862323dcbf854f8/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java) (or some derivative), you will have to change it to handle the escape characters. You should have a class called `SoftKeyboard` which extends `InputMethodService`. Inside there should be a method called `handleCharacter`. Change this line:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 0);
```

To this line:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(primaryCode)), 1);
```

Code Referenced from : [display built-in emoji keys for inputmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004579/display-built-in-emoji-keys-for-inputmethod)

Other References:
http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/customization/how-to-use-emojis-on-your-android-device/

[Emoji Keyboard support for EditField in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899178/emoji-keyboard-support-for-editfield-in-android)

[set font at runtime, Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483110/set-font-at-runtime-textview)

Comment: thank you for reply.. the emoji appear in the keyboard but it didnt write anything .. kindly see the picture http://www8.0zz0.com/2017/08/09/15/386601306.png

Comment: Which font are you using for your Textview/Edittext ? AndroidEmoji.ttf and NotoColorEmoji.ttf is a good ones I think.

Comment: EmojiconEditText is probably what you need:-  https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-integrate-emojis-keyboard-app/

Comment: Android's default font (Roboto, as on 4.0+) includes only monochrome emoji.